# Shockwave Flash Object into C# Surface 2.0 Application, toolbox item hidden

Tags: c#, flash, .net-4.0, pixelsense

I am developing an application for the SUR40 Surface 2.0 table.
I am developing in MS Visual C# 2010 Express .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.

Now I need to embed a Flash file (*.swf) into the Surface Window.

I followed [these steps](http://weblogs.asp.net/twalters/archive/2003/12/29/46265.aspx) and I am stuck at the (Drag the "Shockwave Flash Object" from the toolbox onto the Form (just like any other control)) step.

I couldn't find the Shockwave Flash Object so I tried some things.
After a right-click on the toolbox and select "Show All" the Shockwave Flash Object appears, but its locked. I cant move this Shockwave Flash Object to my Surface Window (see image).

[image: hidden Shockwave Flash Browser]

My questions:

- How can i unlock this toolbox item?
- Is it possible to use Shockwave Flash Object on the Surface 2.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need flash for being as you have C#?

Comment: I want a Flash file running on the Surface. The Surface application get build in C# but the application that has to be openend in my Surface application is an Adobe Air application.

Comment: Because I never used Surface and I bet you $100 if you give me the source code I can remove the dependencies on Flash and Achieve the same thing. Guaranteed. And that goes without knowing what your even doing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

You need to install the latest version of Adobe Macromedia Flash Player . The component will be located at "%systemroot%\system32\macromed\flash11c.ocx". Then you'd better register manually it like this:

Regsvr32 flash11c.ocx

And then please follow these steps to add Shockwave Flash Object correctly on your form in VB 2005 Express:

1. In Solution Explore, right-click References and choose Add Reference.

In COM tab, add Shockwave Flash (e.g. Flash11c.ocx)

1. Right-click Toolbox -> Click "Choose Items", in COM tab, choose Shockwave Flash Object, then you can see the control in the Toolbox.
2. Drag and drop the Shockwave control on the form, you may get the error message "Failed to import the ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered", ignore it and click OK.
3. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, choose "Rebuild". When the project rebuild succesfully, you are able to add the Shockwave control on the form this time.
4. Specify .swf file for the Movie property of Shockwave control.

**or**

Check this link  [Fun With C# and the flash External API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12010/Fun-with-C-and-the-Flash-Player-8-External-API)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right-click on toolbox and press reset button, it will clear all controls added by you.

Click choose item and **do not uncheck any checked option**.

Simply click on your desired .dll control file and press ok, it will add you control and will not disable asp.net controls